# `private` module not export private function when environment :test

Tags: elixir

I want to test `private` function so use `private` module [hex private doc page](https://hexdocs.pm/private/api-reference.html) as follows:

```
defmodule Mechanics.Servo do

  require Logger
  use Private
  private do
  defp check_head(<<>>) do
    Logger.debug(("no data"))
    {:error,:noData}
  end

  defp check_head(<<0x1::8,0x2::8,rest::binary>>) do
    {:ok,rest}
  end

  defp check_head(<<_::8,rest::binary>>) do
    check_head(rest)
      end
end
    end
```

test code

```
defmodule Mechanics.Test do
def a() do
  Mechanics.Servo.check_head(<<0x12,0x4c,1,2,3>>)
end
end
```

mix.exs file is as follows:

```
defmodule Mechanics.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :mechanics,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.13",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :test,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end
```

error message

```
iex(13)> Mechanics.Test.a
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Mechanics.Servo.check_head/1 is undefined or private
    (mechanics 0.1.0) Mechanics.Servo.check_head(<<18, 76, 1, 2, 3>>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/private/readme.html), you should nest the `defp`s that you want to be exposed in a `private` block:

```elixir
defmodule Mechanics.Servo do

  require Logger
  use Private

  private do
    defp check_head(<<>>) do
      Logger.debug(("no data"))
      {:error,:noData}
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I have update the code as above,but the same result.

Comment: Same result in tests? In IEx? When using IEx, are you passing `MIX_ENV=test`?